# Your system has run out of application memory: /tmp directory of tar command

Tags: terminal, command-line, memory, tar

I once extracted a huge tar file in terminal, but it was too big. So, in the middle of the process, my computer ran out of memory, and everything crashed. I rebooted my system, hoping that things get fixed, assuming that the /tmp directory gets wiped at reboot. However, the problem still persists and I often get “out of application memory” nag box for no true reason.

Can someone help me find and erase problematic files created by tar command?

Comment: Not to forget, I have 200 GB free space of disk